# Get the paramether that you pass to php with AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a simple `editCategory()` function to which a pass an `id` as parameter but I don't know what is the correct way to get that `id` in the php code and set it as variable there

```
$scope.EditCategory = function(id) {
        $http.get('details.php', {'id': id})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            ngDialog.open({
                template: "details.html"
            });
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.msg = 'Some error';
            $scope.msg_type = 'error';
        });
    };
```

and in php I want to have `$id = the id that I passed with Angular`

Comment: I think you may want to do a $http.post not .get? On the PHP end either pick up the $_post or you may need to do file_get_contents(')

Comment: thanks I was able to do it this way json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)["id"]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$http.get` so value will be in GET.

`$id = $_GET["id"];`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP.get/post doesn't actually make a true $_post. What you want is to use:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)["id"]
```